# FBSDKMessengerSharer ios GIF sending issue

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am developing apps for ios & droid for sending GIF to fb users using messanger api. The gif from droid to ios works perfect, gif from ios to droid dont animate. In both cases, gif on browser works. Below is sample code for sending gif :

```
            [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareAnimatedGIF:data2 withOptions:nil];
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just sent a GIF from an iOS device to an Android device and it autoplayed just fine. I would test this by doing the same thing with a third party app and seeing what happens.

Comment: Hi,Corvuszero, We fixed it. It was gif encoding issue & size issue.